# rails version not found, even though it's available in the rubygems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I wanted to switch from Rails 4.1.1 to Rails 3.2, because I heard some specific features I am interested in work best in 3.2.
`gem install --http-proxy http://web-proxy:8088 rails –v '3.2.18' --no-rdoc --no-ri` - this command didn't work, no such version (3.2.18) is available so rails 4.1.1 (most recent version) was (re)installed automatically.

Here is the reason:

> Fetching: rails-4.1.1.gem (100%)
>       Successfully installed rails-4.1.1
>       ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'ûv' (>= 0) in any repository
>       ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '3.2.18' (>= 0) in any repository
>       1 gem installed

So: I go to rubygems.org, check list of available rails versions and I see that 3.2.18 (https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/3.2.18) is actually an available version. What am I doing wrong. Why is 3.2.18 not found, if it's on the rubygems site?

I really need Rails 3.2 to have an issue fixed that works poorer in newer Rails versions (according to research in the internet) - many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you copied and pasted parts of your command resulting to non ASCII characters.

In particular, the dash (`-`) seems to be the issue here. Try again with this:

```
gem install --http-proxy http://web-proxy:8088 rails -v '3.2.18' --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

The error message partly gives it away (at least it points to encoding issues) in `Could not find a valid gem 'ûv' (>= 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

First you uninstall latest rails version in your gem. Then install rails 3.2 in your local system and bundle it in your project terminal. And then edit in your gem file as

```
gem 'rails','~3.2'
```

now restart server and run it